# Regex to get everything between first and last double quote but without double quote

Tags: regex, double-quotes

I have following data

```
"full name":"vg","address":"abc, 128, street no 9,"(0112093-0)""
```

Now it is clear in "key":"value" format and it is separated by comma.So I have 2 keys "full name" , "address" . I need to write a regex which will get sting between double quotes only , so something like

```
full name : vg
address : abc, 128, street no 9,"(0112093-0)"
```

I tried following but I am getting double quotes along

```
"(\w+)":"(.*?)"
```

I want to remove the fist and last double quotes from both key and value.

Comment: you mean double quotes within address value ?  Actually it is fine for me if it comes anywhere in between since whole sting is between first and last double quotes

Comment: I am sorry I am new to regex so I am just taking help from google

Comment: So can you please give me the actual solution for this ?

Comment: I also tried following but i am getting both values and keys with double quotes ((?:"[^"]*"|[^:,])*):((?:"[^"]*"|[^,])*)

Comment: There is no solution since data is badly formatted. There is no difference between inner quotes and closing quotes.

Comment: @anubhava That is not true - key is quoted string without followed by color followed by quoted string. Seems straight forward.

Comment: @user3332404 What language/environment? How are you removing outside quotes - replace?

Comment: `Seems straight forward` Look at the value part of `address` field :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/\"(\w+)":"(.*?)"(?=,|$)/g`. [Test it online](https://regex101.com/r/NmnKyC/1)

I have assumed a value can terminate with `",` (might be a boundary case) or `"$`.